# "Global information in constructors" in the MDN JavaScript guide, small query

Tags: javascript, inheritance, constructor

On the MDN JavaScript guide, under the "Property inheritance revisited" section, it explains some of the subtleties of property inheritance.

The one in particular I'm curious about is an example given about an incrementing id:

```
var idCounter = 1;

function Employee (name, dept) {
this.name = name || "";
this.dept = dept || "general";
this.id = idCounter++;
}

function Manager (name, dept, reports) {...}
Manager.prototype = new Employee;

function WorkerBee (name, dept, projs) {...}
WorkerBee.prototype = new Employee;

function Engineer (name, projs, mach) {...}
Engineer.prototype = new WorkerBee;

function SalesPerson (name, projs, quota) {...}
SalesPerson.prototype = new WorkerBee;

var mac = new Engineer("Wood, Mac");
```

Basically, it goes on to say that the completed version of this (each constructor has a 'base' property which also calls the constructor above them in the prototype chain) will mean mac.id will be 5.

I understand that every time an Employee object is created the id value gets incremented by 1, but exactly when are the 4 times before creating 'mac' that an Employee object has been created?
Would be grateful if anyone could give me the process in step by step form.

edit - the page in question: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Details_of_the_Object_Model#Global_information_in_constructors

Comment: Don't you see the 4 lines like `.prototype = new Employee`?

Comment: Could you link that MDN page?

Comment: @Ian: There is only 2 lines visible in the code which explicitly call `new Employee`. The rest of the code is *omitted* which is the part that would make the other 2 calls from the other constructors. The way the MDN page is phrased I can see the how this can cause confusion to people only learning about JavaScript inheritance.

Comment: @FrançoisWahl I understand, but the OP didn't mention they understood why it might make sense for `id` to be **2**. Nor did it mention any notice of those invocations. And I don't see how it matters - you can almost assume the constructors are called of their parents' by the chain the code is creating

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `new` will call the constructor function. Whenever the constructor function is called (either by `new`, or the usual ways, `()`, `call` or `apply`), the id will be incremented. So let's count:

```
Manager.prototype = new Employee; //1
//...
WorkerBee.prototype = new Employee; //2
```

This is two so far. And if you take into account this important sentence under the code:

> Further assume that the definitions omitted here have the `base`
>   property and **call the constructor above them in the prototype chain**.

This basically means that the `{...}` parts in the code are something like this:

```
function Manager (name, dept, reports) {
    Employee.apply(this, arguments);
}
```

[This jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6z5z8/1/) shows the code without these ellipses (minimal implementation).

So these will all call the `Employee` function:

```
Engineer.prototype = new WorkerBee; //3
//...
SalesPerson.prototype = new WorkerBee; //4
//...
var mac = new Engineer("Wood, Mac"); //5
```

Comment: This is not really true. As `this.id` of `mac === 2` and `idCounter === 3` at the end. See here: [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/6z5z8/)

Comment: @FrançoisWahl See the quote from the page that says `Further assume that the definitions omitted here have the base property and call the constructor above them in the prototype chain`. I also added a fiddle to my answer that shows what that means.

Comment: So basically, alongside the 2 which explicitly call a new Employee in the code, the other 2 constructors also call it by being linked through the base property? What confused me is I was messing around with the code myself, and by removing the base property from the WorkerBee constructor, mac.id was 2.

Comment: @kapa: I see. I didn't look at the MDN page itself, I just executed the code. If the they actually call the constructor in the prototype chain then off course the counter will match. (+1)

Comment: @user2999861 Yes, `mac.id` will only be 5 in the end if every constructor calls its parent constructor, which is omitted from the code itself (I don't know why, it would be more comprehensible if they included that). If you don't do this, `mac.id` will be 2, because the `Employee` function is only called twice directly.

Comment: @user2999861: As a side note, If you don't want to execute the constructor at the time of inheritance you can use the newer `Object.create()` instead. ie: `WorkerBee.prototype = Object.create(Employee.prototype);` That will result in the same inheritance but without executing the `Employee` constructor at that moment. If you then want to make sure the WorkerBee uses it's own constructor you can in re-set it .i.e: `WorkerBee.prototype.constructor = WorkerBee; // following the Object.create() / = new Employee line` The WorkerBee constructor can then use `Employee.call(...)` for more control.

Comment: @FrançoisWahl Thanks for adding that. I use `Object.create()` too for inheritance, `new` is way too messy for that (as we see :)).

Comment: So to be clear, why is the reason mac.id would be 2 when you remove the base property from this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/uY6as/ ? Why is it not 3? The 2 'new Employee' calls plus the creation of mac? Sorry to keep on, but there's obviously something basic I can't quite grasp about it.

Comment: `this.base = Employee; this.base(name, dept, test);` basically means `Employee(name, dept, test)` - so it calls the `Employee` function - which will increment the id. The `base` itself is not that important here, what matters is that the function gets called.

Comment: Ah, I see. So then the Employee function gets called twice more because the other 2 constructor's prototypes are WorkerBee. By my count though, without this 'base' calling the function, it should be called twice (once for each of the prototypes being set as Employee), meaning 2 increments before mac is created, so why is mac.id 2 rather than 3?

Comment: @user2999861 Because the last line is `var mac = new WorkerBee("Wood, Mac");` in your example. It only calls `WorkerBee` - so if the `WorkerBee` function calls its base constructor, this counts as +1, otherwise it does not count, because the `Employee` constructor does not get called directly.

Comment: @kapa Ah ok, got it now :) thanks for putting up with my stupidity, I'm still quite new to this.

Comment: @user2999861 I see no stupidity. Keep on learning and you will be great.

Answer (score 0):

John Resig has an excellent article, and simple helper function, on [how to use class-based inheritance](http://ejohn.org/blog/simple-javascript-inheritance/).  This makes it easier to inherit from a base class, without calling the constructor.

Here's my own explanation:

In order for `Manager` to inherit from `Employee`, `Manager.prototype` must actually be an **instance** of an `Employee`.  So, `Manager.prototype = new Employee` will actually execute the `Employee` constructor immediately.

The only way around this, is to put the constructor logic into a separate method, such as `init`:

```
function Employee() { /* EMPTY CONSTRUCTOR */ }
Employee.prototype.init = function(name, dept) {
  this.name = name || "";
  this.dept = dept || "general";
  this.id = idCounter++;
}

function Manager(name, dept, reports) {
    this.init(name, dept); // Calls the base constructor
}
Manager.prototype = new Employee();
```

Comment: I would argue the *only way*. `Object.create()` instead of `new` for the inheritance also solves the problem.

Comment: @kapa I'd argue both are equally bad, moving global state somewhere or calling it a chicken doesn't stop it from being global state. The correct approach would be to have an Employee repository that takes care of identification if at all, since each object already has a unique ID, its reference.